# Count of messages in the group

Tags: wtelegramclient

Is it possible that there are more messages in the Chat/Channel full history than the maximum int value ?

https://wiz0u.github.io/WTelegramClient/EXAMPLES.html#fetch-all-messages-history-from-a-chatuser

Answer (score 1):

No. Message IDs are `int` so it can be more than `int.MaxValue`

It is undefined what would happen if a Telegram group/channel reaches this limit.

Some people say it will wrap around to zero and all the old messages are lost, only the new ones would be accessible.